# How do i include RVO2 library in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, linker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rvo

I have been writing a code which uses SDL to render particles in Visual Studio. However, there does not seem to be any way to include RVO2 library:
http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/RVO2/downloads/ to Visual Studio. I have been able to include header files, but library file seems to be libRVO.a which Visual Studio is maybe not accepting. Also, there is no .dll file as was with SDL2 download.

So, I wanted to ask is there any way in which I can use RVO library in Visual Studio.

If not, I have another similar question...
I am using wsl(Windows Subsystem for Linux) and found that SDL cannot be run in it. I am able include RVO in wsl. So, can you suggest me a way where I can use both the libraries RVO and SDL2 simultaneously...